# I cannot access de href direction using sprin boot

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am noobie with springboot, so I think this error is easy to fix, but I don't know what to do, I have this:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="@{/updateAlertsUser}" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
```

On an html, and I have this code on a controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateAlertsUser", method=RequestMethod.POST) 
public void updateAlertsUser(@ModelAttribute("userAlerts") @Valid UserAlertsDto userAlertsDto,
            BindingResult result,Principal principal, Model model)   {
      
    if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
        log.info("Intentando actualizar las alertas vistas por el usuario"); 
    }       
    
    userAlertsService.deleteLogic(userAlertsDto);       
}
```

I think is correct and when I click on the icon that has the href, it goes to the updateAlertsUser method on the controller, but it doesn't do anything.

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Apparently you are using thymeleaf use `th:href` not `href`.

Comment: I addth_href, and doesn't work. don't do anything

Comment: `th:href` **not** `th_href`. Also make sure it is a valid thymeleaf template. Looks like you are copy pasting things without knowing what it does.

Answer (score -1):

```
<a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/updateAlertsUser}" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
```

Comment: I try this answer, and doesn't work, don't do anything